# Disable SSL on specific subdomain

Tags: apache, ssl-certificate, subdomain

I have a domain say example.com using SSL. Now i have created a test site for the application and hosted in test.example.com. But whenever i am trying to access test.example.com i am getting connection not private error. That sub domain is also using the SSL somehow.

I tried to add redirect rule to http version in .htaccess and vhost files, but not working. Any solution?

Here is the default-ssl.conf file:

```
    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
            <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            DocumentRoot /var/www/html/frontend
            DirectoryIndex index.html
     <Directory /var/www/html/frontend>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
            #LogLevel info ssl:warn

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
 SSLEngine On

                SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certfile.crt
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certkey.key
                SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: If there's no matching vhost for that domain apache will serve the default one. But that means that you are trying to access test.example.com over https so your `RewriteRule` might be wrong.

Comment: i have create a vhost file for test sub domain on for port 80. but when i am trying to access it on http it redirects it to https.

Comment: Does your certificate list `test.example.com` or `*.example.com`? If not, then it does not cover your second website.

Comment: I don't want to use SSL on second website. I an trying to access it without SSL but it automatically redirects to SSL version, and i guess SSL is only for example.com.